# Magnetic field outside a toroidal surface with a sheet current

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, maxwell-equations

The integral from of Ampere's law is $\int \mathbf{B}\cdot d\mathbf{l} = \mu_0 I$. Let's say our contour of integration $\mathbf{l}$ is a contour on the surface of a toroidal surface. Also, let the magnetic field $\mathbf{B}$ be generated by a sheet current on this toroidal surface.

For a torus, this integral indicates that the magnetic field outside of the toroidal surface is zero (this is after applying the property that the magnetic field lines of $\mathbf{B}$ are tangent to the toroidal surface, I believe this is called "toroidal symmetry" for the magnetic field).

For a general toroidal surface (not necessarily a torus, let's assume a random toroidal surface like this one: [https://terpconnect.umd.edu/~mattland/projects/6_optimization/](https://terpconnect.umd.edu/%7Emattland/projects/6_optimization/) ), the integral still has the same result $\int \mathbf{B}\cdot d\mathbf{l} = \mu_0 I = 0$ given that the enclosed current is zero.

Now, for a general toroidal surface, it is very hard to know if the magnetic field lines are tangential to the surface so I just wanted to check if it's possible to generalize this result.

Does the result $\int \mathbf{B}\cdot d\mathbf{l} = 0$ indicate that $\mathbf{B}$ is zero outside of the toroidal surface for any toroidal surface with a sheet current on it?

Answer (score 0):

H = *B is the current density in a thin metallic surface by Maxwells definitions. For a torus, place a small circle of integration parallel or orthogonal to its graeatest outer tangent circle  penetrating the surface.

Circle axis parallel to equator yields the ring current density as source of the outer dipol field, inner field zero, circle axis parallel to the torus axis yields the ring core transformer current component ,source of the inner constant ring field with external field zero. See cohomology of manifolds, that is number of independent (current) vector fields on manifolds in corrspondence to the number shortest closed paths, methods to count the holes.

Comment: would you please let me know what *B means?